# How can I add a "no result" text?

Tags: 7, views

I am using contextual filters to populate a view.

How can I display a text like *No results found* when the view doesn't show any result?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's under 'Advanced' on the right hand side. Then 'add' a NO RESULTS BEHAVIOUR.

Answer (score 3):

You can also add a "no results behavior" view element in code in your own module.

That's useful if the element has to be dynamic – in the example below, it's a configurable button to add content to the view. (Content is added to an [OG](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) group with a node ID supplied as contextual filter parameter to the view.)

```
/**
 * Implements hook_views_pre_render().
 */
function MYMODULE_views_pre_render(&$view) {
  if($view->name != 'my_view_machine_name') {
    return;
  }

  if (isset($view->args[0])) {
    $target_group_nid = $view->args[0];
    $button_html = _generateButtonHtml($target_group_nid);

    // Create a "Global: Textarea" view element.
    $options = array(
      'id' => 'button2',
      'table' => 'views',
      'field' => 'area',
      'empty' => FALSE,
      'content' => '<div>No results yet. Add one:</div>' . $button_html,
      'format' => 'filtered_html',
      'tokenize' => 0,
    );
    $view->set_item('default', 'empty', 'button2', $options);
  }
}
```

Note: `_generateButtonHtml()` is just a stub for your own function to return HTML code for a button.

**Relevant API docs:**

- [`hook_views_pre_render()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!views!views.api.php/function/hook_views_pre_render/7)
- [`$view→set_item()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/views_db_object%3A%3Aset_item/7)
- [`views_object_types()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/includes!view.inc/function/views_object_types/7) for other view elements you can set in `$view->set_item()` than just `empty` for the "no result behaviour"